# Generic: Naming structure and drawing KineticJS

Tags: javascript, canvas, air, kineticjs

This one takes a bit more to describe, sorry for the shorter title.

I currently do not have my code in front of me but might update this with the full details of how it works and where the problem is located.

Basically I notice that without doing a more or less global name (window.whatever) for the shapes/groups it will never draw them. I have done logs of the objects to see if they are proper and have seen nothing wrong with them.

The full scope is a layer first, that is passed to a function that i then create shapes and groups in a logical way, without passing the groups back and instead sending the layer as a parameter to add it from within the function. When I do it this way it seems that I can never get it to draw to the container (stage).

To add to it, I am looping to create the shapes, as I am making them variable and more percentage based then exact pixels, so I am holding the objects in an array that is generated through the loop.

I have done this flat first and it worked, however after moving it to the function it stopped working, is there any reason for this I may be missing?

Another note if it is relevant, I am using Adobe AIR.

If anyone has any ideas let me know, I will post the actual code when I can (few hours from this posting).

UPDATE:

Basically the issue I am having is that when i separate the shapes/groups into their own function it does not want to draw them at all. I have tried to call the draw function inline and also just add them to the stage later, both to my understanding will trigger the draw.

here is the code

```
var forms = {
    selector:function(params,bind){

        //globals
        var parent,obj,lastWidth=0,items=[];

        //setup defaults
        var params = params || {};
        params.x = params.x || 0;
        params.y = params.y || 0;
        params.active = params.active || 0;
        params.height = params.height || 200;
        params.children = params.children || [{
            fill:'yellow'
        }];
        params.width = params.width || bind.getWidth();
        params.margins = params.margins || 5;

        //container for selector
        parent = new Kinetic.Group({
            x:params.x,
            y:params.y,
            height:params.height,
            width:params.width
        });
        air.Introspector.Console.log(params);

        var totalMargins = params.margins*(params.children.length+1),
            activeWidth = (params.width-totalMargins)/2,
            subItems = params.children.length-1,
            subWidth = activeWidth/subItems,
            itemHeight = (params.height-params.margins)/2;
        //loop all children
        for(var i=0;i<params.children.length;i++){
            //use an array to store objects
            items[i]={};
            //create default object for rectangle
            obj = {};
            obj.y = params.margins;
            obj.fill = params.children[i].fill;
            if(params.active==i){
                obj.width = activeWidth;
            }else{
                obj.width = subWidth;
            }
            obj.x = params.margins+lastWidth;
            obj.height = itemHeight;
            lastWidth = lastWidth+(params.margins+obj.width);
            //create group for text
            items[i].text = new Kinetic.Group({
                x:0,
                y:itemHeight+params.margins
            });
            //create box for text
            items[i].box = new Kinetic.Rect({
                x: params.margins,
                y: params.margins,
                width:params.width-(params.margins*2),
                height:(params.height-itemHeight)-(params.margins*2),
                fill:'yellow'
            });
            air.Introspector.Console.log(items[i].box);
            //add box to text groups
            items[i].text.add(items[i].box);
            //create item
            items[i].item = new Kinetic.Rect(obj);

            //add groups to parent
            parent
                .add(items[i].item)
                .add(items[i].text);
        }
        //add parent to the bound container
        bind.add(parent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't understand what you're asking...Does this example help: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/453n6/

Comment: It actually might, gonna update the question and should be able to show my code soon. Yours shows a slight alteration to what I am doing, I will have to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have since figured it out.

The issue is that the layer must be added to the stage before anything else is added it it. It was not in my code because I did not see it as an issue as it worked elsewhere.

Basically if you add anything to a layer, then add the layer to the stage it will fail. it must go like this:

CREATE STAGE

CREATE LAYER

ADD LAYER TO STAGE

ADD GROUPS TO LAYER

DRAW IF NEEDED

The way it was done originally is like so:

CREATE STAGE

CREATE LAYER

ADD GROUPS TO LAYER

ADD LAYER TO STAGE

DRAW IF NEEDED

The question will be updated to make this apparent, this is something that is not in the documentation as a problem (as far as I have seen) and I can see it as confusing some.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I'm assuming `bind` is your Kinetic.Layer.

1. Make sure bind has been added to the stage: stage.add(bind);
2. After adding your groups/rects to bind, also do bind.draw();

Comment: Close but it was the ordering of the adding in the end, my rep is low because of bounties but I would upvote if I could.